# Form nine squares from three squares

Tags: geometry

Can you draw three squares on a piece of paper, such that they form nine distinct squares?

Good luck!

Comment: the accepted answer has 6 non-distinct squares so technically there is no answer

Comment: @TruVortex_07 Can you explain what you mean by "6 non-distinct squares"?

Comment: distinct means different. However the answer has congruent squares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the answer you are looking for?

> [image] 
>  Just draw the yellow, the blue then the red one like this: 
> [image]

Comment: Yes that is correct! Well done. Stay tuned for more questions in this theme.